# Recursively traverse multidimensional associative array and create key path strings

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have following multi dimensional associative array, I am trying to recursively traverse it and create array with each element parent tree

Input array:

```
$user = [
    'profile' => [
        'authkey' => '',
        'publickey' => '',
        'status' => 19
    ],
    'setup' => [
        'profile' => false,
        'contact' => false,
        'payments' => false,
        'subscription' => false
    ],
    'paygateway' => [
        'paypal' => [
            'publickey' =>'',
            'secretkey' => '',
            'testarray' => [
                'key1' => 'value1',
                'key2' => 'value2',
                'key3' => [
                    'key4' => 'level4'
                ]
            ],
            'webhookid' => ''
        ],    
        'stripe' => [
            'publickey' => '',
            'secretkey' => ''
        ]
    ]
];
```

Required output:

```
array (
  'profile' => 
  array (
    0 => '[profile][authkey]',
    1 => '[profile][publickey]',
    2 => '[profile][status]',
  ),
  'setup' => 
  array (
    0 => '[setup][profile]',
    1 => '[setup][contacts]',
    2 => '[setup][payments]',
    3 => '[setup][subscriptions]',
  ),
  'paygateway' => 
  array (
    0 => '[paygateway][paypal][publickey]',
    1 => '[paygateway][paypal][secretkey]',
    2 => '[paygateway][paypal][testarray][key1]',
    3 => '[paygateway][paypal][testarray][key2]',
    4 => '[paygateway][paypal][testarray][key3][key4]',
    5 => '[paygateway][paypal][webhookid]',
    6 => '[paygateway][stripe][publickey]',
    7 => '[paygateway][stripe][secretkey]',
  ),
)
```

What I already have:

The following function that perfectly goes through entire tree of the array:

```
function testArray($array){
    
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo "$key <br/>";
            testArray($value);
        }else{
            echo "$key : $value <br/>";
        }   
        
    }
}
testArray($user);
```

I am unable to figure out how to add up the keys from structure and build the output array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the original first level keys, I recommend passing each first level value into the recursive function.

In the recursive function, build the formatted key path string as you conditionally traverse deeper on subarrays.  Return the populated key paths on each level and push all deeper populated paths upon ascending the tree.

Regarding the `array_push()` line, it is being used to individually append all elements from the deeper level's returned result to the current level's result. It could have been written as:
`$result = array_merge($result, buildKeyPath($value, "{$path}[$key]"));`
but I find data "spreading" with `array_push()` to be more indicative of the type of process being executed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cRJ6m))

```
function buildKeyPath(array $array, string $path): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            array_push($result, ...buildKeyPath($value, "{$path}[$key]"));
        } else {
            $result[] = "{$path}[$key]";
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

foreach ($user as $k => &$v) {
   $v = buildKeyPath($v, "[$k]");
}
var_export($user);
```

Comment: Hi could you pls make it with array_merge I tried but got undesired results. also what if I have key pair in the root structure as well where value is not an array but a simple value?  I am struggling with another thing I'll probably need help with soon.

Comment: [With `array_merge()`](https://3v4l.org/VjaHK) Please offer me a 3v4l demo hyperlink with yournew, challenging sample data and explain your desired result as `/* commented code */` on the demo.

Comment: I was able to get through the other part I was working. I'll be glad if you could help me with this only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74049005/how-to-find-if-path-exists-in-an-associative-array-while-using-dynamic-path